# The Transition of my side mobile menu does'nt work

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I want to make my mobile menu slide from rigth to left when I click on the hamburger menu. But it does'nt work someone knows why? I tried by changing width (0vw=>50vw) for the transition and with margin (100%=>50%) but nothing seems to work...

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>Thomas Ghysel Design</title>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
        <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Red+Hat+Display:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
        <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="primary-header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="nav-wrapper">
                    <a href="#accueil">
                        <img class="logo" src="img/logo_TG.svg" alt="Thomas Ghysel" />
                    </a>

                    <button
                        class="mobile-nav-toggle"
                        aria-label="Menu"
                        aria-controls="primary-navigation"
                    >
                        <svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                            <path
                                class="line line1"
                                d="M 20,29.000046 H 80.000231 C 80.000231,29.000046 94.498839,28.817352 94.532987,66.711331 94.543142,77.980673 90.966081,81.670246 85.259173,81.668997 79.552261,81.667751 75.000211,74.999942 75.000211,74.999942 L 25.000021,25.000058"
                            />
                            <path class="line line2" d="M 20,50 H 80" />
                            <path
                                class="line line3"
                                d="M 20,70.999954 H 80.000231 C 80.000231,70.999954 94.498839,71.182648 94.532987,33.288669 94.543142,22.019327 90.966081,18.329754 85.259173,18.331003 79.552261,18.332249 75.000211,25.000058 75.000211,25.000058 L 25.000021,74.999942"
                            /></svg
                        ><span class="visually-hidden">Menu</span>
                    </button>

                    <nav class="primary-navigation" id="primary-navigation">
                        <ul role="list" class="nav-list">
                            <li><a href="#accueil">Accueil</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#gallerie">Galerie</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>

        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* Box sizing rules */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Remove default margin */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font: inherit;
}

/* Remove list styles on ul, ol elements with a list role, which suggests default styling will be removed */
ul[role="list"],
ol[role="list"] {
    list-style: none;
}

/* Set core root defaults */
html:focus-within {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

/* Set core body defaults */
body {
    text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

/* A elements that don't have a class get default styles */
a:not([class]) {
    text-decoration-skip-ink: auto;
}

/* Make images easier to work with */
img,
picture {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

/* Remove all animations, transitions and smooth scroll for people that prefer not to see them */
@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
    html:focus-within {
        scroll-behavior: auto;
    }

    *,
    *::before,
    *::after {
        animation-duration: 0.01ms !important;
        animation-iteration-count: 1 !important;
        transition-duration: 0.01ms !important;
        scroll-behavior: auto !important;
    }
}

:root {
    --clr-primary-400: hsl(346, 66%, 44%);
    --clr-primary-opacity: hsl(346, 66%, 44%);

    --clr-accent-400: hsl(175, 100%, 21%);
    --clr-accent-300: hsl(27, 70%, 69%);

    --clr-neutral-100: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    --clr-neutral-900: hsl(273, 100%, 4%);

    --ff-primary: "Red Hat Display", sans-serif;

    --ff-body: var(--ff-primary);
    --ff-heading: var(--ff-primary);

    --fw-light: 300;
    --fw-regular: 400;
    --fw-medium: 500;
    --fw-semibold: 600;
    --fw-bold: 700;
    --fw-extrabold: 800;
    --fw-black: 900;

    --fw-body: var(--fw-regular);
    --fw-primary-heading: var(--fw-black);
    --fw-secondary-heading: var(--fw-bold);
    --fw-primary-nav: var(--fw-regular);
    --fw-service-heading: var(--fw-extrabold);
    --fw-button: var(--fw-medium);

    --fs-300: 0.8rem;
    --fs-400: 1rem;
    --fs-450: 1.2rem;
    --fs-500: 1.5rem;
    --fs-600: 2rem;
    --fs-700: 2.5rem;
    --fs-900: 5rem;

    --fs-body: var(--fs-300);
    --fs-primary-heading: var(--fs-900);
    --fs-secondary-heading: var(--fs-700);
    --fs-primary-nav: var(--fs-400);
    --fs-service-heading: var(--fs-600);
    --fs-button: var(--fs-300);

    --padding-block-100: 0.5rem;
    --padding-block-200: 0.75rem;
    --padding-block-300: 1rem;
    --padding-block-350: 1.5rem;
    --padding-block-400: 2rem;
    --padding-block-500: 3rem;
    --padding-block-600: 4rem;
    --padding-block-700: 5rem;
    --padding-block-800: 6rem;
    --padding-block-900: 7rem;
    --padding-block-1000: 10rem;
}

/* General styling */

body {
    font-family: var(--ff-body);
    font-size: var(--fs-body);
    font-weight: var(--fw-body);
    color: var(--clr-neutral-900);
    background-color: var(--clr-neutral-100);
}

.section {
    padding-block: var(--padding-block-900);
    padding-inline: 2rem;
}

.even-columns {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 1rem;
}

/* button */

.button {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 100vmax;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    font-weight: var(--fw-button);
    font-size: var(--fs-button);
    background-color: var(--clr-primary-400);
    color: var(--clr-neutral-100);
    border: 0.1em solid transparent;
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: var(--clr-primary-400);
    border: 0.1em solid var(--clr-primary-400);
}

/* Header */

.primary-header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    margin-bottom: var(--padding-block-900);
    padding-block: var(--padding-block-350);
    z-index: 99;
    background-color: var(--clr-neutral-100);
    padding-inline: 2rem;
}

.logo {
    width: 15rem;
}

/* Navigation  */
.nav-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav-list {
    display: flex;
    gap: 3rem;
}

.nav-list a {
    color: var(--clr-neutral-100);
    text-decoration: none;
}

.primary-navigation a {
    color: var(--clr-neutral-900);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: var(--fw-medium);
}

.nav-list a:hover {
    color: var(--clr-primary-400);
}

/* Active link */
ul li a.active {
    color: var(--clr-primary-400);
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
/* Hamburger menu */
.mobile-nav-toggle {
    display: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
}
.mobile-nav-toggle svg {
    display: none;
    width: 4rem;
    z-index: 99;
}
.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: var(--clr-neutral-900);
    stroke-width: 6;
    transition: stroke-dasharray 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1),
        stroke-dashoffset 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}
.line1 {
    stroke-dasharray: 60 207;
    stroke-width: 6;
}
.line2 {
    stroke-dasharray: 60 60;
    stroke-width: 6;
}
.line3 {
    stroke-dasharray: 60 207;
    stroke-width: 6;
}
.opened .line1 {
    stroke-dasharray: 90 207;
    stroke-dashoffset: -134;
    stroke-width: 6;
}
.opened .line2 {
    stroke-dasharray: 1 60;
    stroke-dashoffset: -30;
    stroke-width: 6;
}
.opened .line3 {
    stroke-dasharray: 90 207;
    stroke-dashoffset: -134;
    stroke-width: 6;
}
/* Responsive Menu */

.visually-hidden {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 0;
}

.nav-list {
    font-size: var(--fs-primary-nav);
    font-weight: var(--fw-primary-nav);
}

@media (max-width: 50em) {
    .primary-header {
        padding-inline: 1rem;

        padding-block: 0;
    }
    .mobile-nav-toggle svg {
        display: block;
    }
    .primary-navigation {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        background-color: var(--clr-primary-opacity);
        width: 0vw;
        height: 100vh;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 0;
        padding-top: 10rem;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }

    .primary-navigation-mobile {
        display: block;
        width: 50vw;
    }

    .nav-list {
        display: grid;
        gap: var(--padding-block-600);
        text-align: right;
        padding-right: 3rem;
        font-size: var(--fs-500);
    }

    .nav-list a {
        color: var(--clr-neutral-100);
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .nav-list a:hover {
        color: var(--clr-neutral-900);
    }
}

/* Profile picture */

.profil-img-show {
    position: absolute;
}
.profil-img-hidden {
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.profil-img-show ~ .profil-img-hidden:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    scale: 1.01;
}

@media (max-width: 60em) {
    .profil-img-hidden {
        display: none;
    }

    .profil-img-show {
        position: relative;
    }
}
```

JS:

```
// Copyrights Current year
var date = new Date();
var year = date.getFullYear();
document.getElementById("current-year").innerHTML = year;

// Responsive Menu
const navToggle = document.querySelector(".mobile-nav-toggle");
const primaryNav = document.querySelector(".primary-navigation");

navToggle.addEventListener("click", () => {
    primaryNav.classList.toggle("primary-navigation-mobile");
    navToggle.classList.toggle("opened");
    navToggle.setAttribute(
        "aria-expanded",
        navToggle.classList.contains("opened")
    );
});

// Active link
```

I want to make my mobile menu slide from rigth to left when I click on the hamburger menu. But it does'nt work someone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

Hello so I tried running your code myself, once I saw it was not working I opened the console (F12 or Right-Click and Inspect Element). There I could see an error on line 4 of your `main.js`.

Here is a screenshot of the error: [Error Screenshot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKY14.png)

This error was caused because the element with id "current-year" you were targeting for the year value does not exist in your HTML, or it did exist but maybe you removed it.

Therefore, as the `main.js` file was failing at line 4, the function below that was not executing at all. Once line 4 is commented out, the menu opens as it should from the right to the left when pressing the button.

Here is the code for `main.js` now:

```js
// Copyrights Current year
var date = new Date();
var year = date.getFullYear();
// document.getElementById("current-year").innerHTML = year;

// Responsive Menu
const navToggle = document.querySelector(".mobile-nav-toggle");
const primaryNav = document.querySelector(".primary-navigation");

navToggle.addEventListener("click", () => {
    primaryNav.classList.toggle("primary-navigation-mobile");
    navToggle.classList.toggle("opened");
    navToggle.setAttribute(
        "aria-expanded",
        navToggle.classList.contains("opened")
    );
});

// Active link
```

You can either have line 4 commented out, or you can add an element with that id in your HTML so that the code can work.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hello! thank you for the answer. Unfortunally even with the line 4 in my .js commented it does'nt work for m... the menu appears but with no transition... I tried in Codepen just in case but same result.. https://codepen.io/Thomghy/pen/ExdYyLG

Comment: You can't use transition for display. When you set `display: block` there is no transition that can happen from `none` to `block`. Try using something else like opacity or translate.


e.g.
`opacity: 0` - When hidden
`opacity: 1` - To show

Comment: Hello, I just found my mistake. I put ‘display: none’ so there was no transition. I just took it off and everything is working fine. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad you made it work now. Good luck with the rest of your project!